# How does Paging 3.0 data caching differ from caching data from network in the Room database?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-paging-3

As far as I know, one of the uses of Paging3 is to cache the data from the xxxPagingSource. Does it mean I don't have to cache my network calls anymore?

> In-memory caching for your paged data. This ensures that your app uses system resources efficiently while working with paged data. [[...]](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview)

Does it mean that if I have like a thousand of ItemUiStates I want page and display like 20 of them at once, do I not do the "fetch_from_the_network&save_in_room&hope_it_notifies_ui" behavior and rely on Paging3's caching?

What about the "single source of truth"-principle? How should I organize my classes to use Paging, Retrofit and Room together? How do I introduce states like IN_PROGRESS, ERROR, OK?